# JQuery получить все данные формы

Tags: jquery, php

Как получить данные из формы, например

```
<form name="form1" method="post">
   <input type="radio" name="foo" value="1" checked="checked" />
   <input type="radio" name="foo" value="0" />
   <input type="text" value="John" name="Fname" />
   <input type="text" name="Lname" />
   <select name="this">
      <option value="on" selected="selected">ON</option>
      <option value="off">OFF</option>
   </select>
</form>
```

получить из jquery на php, в таком виде.

```
{"Fname":"John","Lname":"","foo":"1","this":"on"}
```

Comment: [.serializeArray()][1]

[1]: https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Comment: @Smash, судя по вопросу человек хочет получить объект, а не массив. Причем здесь serializeArray?

Answer (score 2):

```
//добавим в jQuery нужный метод
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
   var o = {};
   var a = this.serializeArray();
   $.each(a, function() {
       if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
           if (!o[this.name].push) {
               o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
           }
           o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
       } else {
           o[this.name] = this.value || '';
       }
   });
   return o;
};
//используем новый метод на нужной форме
var _object = $("form[name='form1']").serializeObject();
```