# Checkbox всегда передаёт ON

Tags: html, javascript

В форме чекбокс всегда передаёт ON, вне зависимости,
отмечен чекбокс галочкой, или нет. Почему он себя так ведет?
Как сделать отправку ON только при отмеченном чекбоксе?

```
    <form id="CalcForm" name="CalcForm" action="#" method="post">

    <input id="wsize1" name="wsize1" type="hidden" value="165">
        <input id="wsize2" name="wsize2" type="hidden" value="165">
        <input id="wsize3" name="wsize3" type="hidden" value="165">
        <input id="wsize4" name="wsize4" type="hidden" value="165">
        <input id="dsize1" name="dsize1" type="hidden" value="165">
        <input id="dsize2" name="dsize2" type="hidden" value="165">

    <input id="type_window" name="type_window" type="hidden" value="okno">
        <input id="col_stv" name="col_stv" type="hidden" value="2">
        <input id="stv1" name="stv1" type="hidden" value="no">
        <input id="stv2" name="stv2" type="hidden" value="no">
        <input id="stv3" name="stv3" type="hidden" value="no">
        <input id="furnitura" name="furnitura" type="hidden" value="Roto NT KSR">
        <input id="glubina" name="glubina" type="hidden" value="250 мм РБК">
        <input id="steklopaket" name="steklopaket" type="hidden" value="Однокамерный">
        <input id="profil" name="profil" type="hidden" value="- системы 58">
        <input id="ruchka" name="ruchka" type="hidden" value="Ручка Hoppe, белая">

    <div class="dif_box_list dblmarg dblmargleft">Фурнитура:<br>
        <div id="dd1" class="wrapper-dropdown-1" tabindex="1">
            <span>Roto NT</span>
            <ul class="dropdown" tabindex="1" style="z-index: 50;">
                <li><a href="#" id="furnitura1">Roto NT</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="furnitura2">Roto NT KSR</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="dif_box_list dblmarg">Глубина подоконника:<br>
        <div id="dd2" class="wrapper-dropdown-1" tabindex="1">
            <span>Ширина 150 мм РБК</span>
            <ul class="dropdown" tabindex="1" style="z-index: 50;">
                <li><a href="#" id="glubina1">Ширина 150 мм РБК</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="glubina2">200 мм РБК</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="glubina3">250 мм РБК</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="glubina4">300 мм РБК</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="glubina5">350 мм РБК</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="glubina6">400 мм РБК</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="glubina7">450 мм РБК</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="glubina8">500 мм РБК</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="glubina9">550 мм РБК</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="glubina10">600 мм РБК</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="dif_box_list dblmarg">Тип стеклопакета:<br>
        <div id="dd3" class="wrapper-dropdown-1" tabindex="1">
            <span>Однокамерный</span>
            <ul class="dropdown" tabindex="1" style="z-index: 50;">
                <li><a href="#" id="steklopaket1">Однокамерный</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="steklopaket2">Двухкамерный</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="dif_box_list dblmargleft">Тип профиля:<br>
        <div id="dd4" class="wrapper-dropdown-1" tabindex="1" style="z-index: 40;">
            <span>- системы 58</span>
            <ul class="dropdown" tabindex="1">
                <li><a href="#" id="profil1">- системы 58</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="profil2">KBE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="profil3">REHAU</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="profil4">MONTBLANC ECO</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="profil5">REACHMONT</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="profil6">VEKA</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="profil7">-системы 70</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="profil8">KBE</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="profil9">REHAU</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="profil10">VEKA</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="dif_box_list">Ручка:<br>
        <div id="dd5" class="wrapper-dropdown-1" tabindex="1" style="z-index: 40;">
            <span>Ручка internika</span>
            <ul class="dropdown" tabindex="1">
                <li><a href="#" id="ruchka1">Ручка internika</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="ruchka2">Ручка Compact, белая</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="ruchka3">Ручка Hoppe, белая</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>  
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="dif_box_list dblmargleft">Москитные сетки:
    <div class="dbl_check_one">
        <input id="check_one" name="set1" type="checkbox" class="checkbox label1">
        <label for="check_one" class="label label1">На окно</label>
        <input id="check_two" name="set2" type="checkbox" class="checkbox label2">
        <label for="check_two" class="label label2">На дверь</label>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <input id="check_three" name="set3" type="checkbox" class="checkbox label3">
        <label for="check_three" class="label label3">На дверь</label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="dif_box_list">Дополнительно:    
    <div class="dbl_check_one">
        <input id="check_four" name="dopm1" type="checkbox" class="checkbox label4">
        <label for="check_four" class="label label4">Защита от детей</label>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <input id="check_five" name="dopm2" type="checkbox" class="checkbox label5">
        <label for="check_five" class="label label5">Ручка с замком</label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="calc_refresh"><a class="refresh_link">Повторить расчет</a></div>

<!-- ***************************** -->

<div id="dim">
<div class="window_form">
    <div class="close"></div>
        <div class="delivery_form_title">Заполните форму для<br>заказа расчета стоимости</div>

        <input name="name" type="text" class="delivery_name" placeholder="Введите Ваше имя"><br>
            <input name="phone" type="text" class="delivery_phone phone3" placeholder="Введите Ваш телефон"><br>
            <input name="email" type="text" class="delivery_email" placeholder="Введите Вашу почту"><br>

            <button>Рассчитать стоимость</button>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- ***************************** -->

</form>
```

JS

```
function sendForm(form) 
{
    var data = 
    {
        name: $(form).find('input[name="name"]').val(),
        phone: $(form).find('input[name="phone"]').val(),
        email: $(form).find('input[name="email"]').val(),

        wsize1: $(form).find('input[name="wsize1"]').val(),
        wsize2: $(form).find('input[name="wsize2"]').val(),
        wsize3: $(form).find('input[name="wsize3"]').val(),
        wsize4: $(form).find('input[name="wsize4"]').val(),
        dsize1: $(form).find('input[name="dsize1"]').val(),
        dsize2: $(form).find('input[name="dsize2"]').val(),
        type_window: $(form).find('input[name="type_window"]').val(),
        col_stv: $(form).find('input[name="col_stv"]').val(),
        stv1: $(form).find('input[name="stv1"]').val(),
        stv2: $(form).find('input[name="stv2"]').val(),
        stv3: $(form).find('input[name="stv3"]').val(),
        furnitura: $(form).find('input[name="furnitura"]').val(),
        glubina: $(form).find('input[name="glubina"]').val(),
        steklopaket: $(form).find('input[name="steklopaket"]').val(),
        profil: $(form).find('input[name="profil"]').val(),
        ruchka: $(form).find('input[name="ruchka"]').val(),

        set1: $(form).find('input[name="set1"]').val(),
        set2: $(form).find('input[name="set2"]').val(),
        set3: $(form).find('input[name="set3"]').val(),
        dopm1: $(form).find('input[name="dopm1"]').val(),
        dopm2: $(form).find('input[name="dopm2"]').val()

    }

    switch (form.id) 
    {
        case 'HeaderForm': data['form'] = 'HeaderForm'; break;
        case 'DeliveryForm': data['form'] = 'DeliveryForm'; break;
        case 'ConsultForm': data['form'] = 'ConsultForm'; break;
        case 'FooterForm': data['form'] = 'FooterForm'; break;
        case 'CWForm': data['form'] = 'CWForm'; break;
        case 'CalcForm': data['form'] = 'CalcForm'; break;
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'mailer.php',
        data: data,
        success: function() {

            $(form).find('input,textarea').each(function(){$(this).val('')});

            $("#dim, #dim2").fadeOut('fast', function() 
            {
                $("#dim3").fadeIn();
                setTimeout(function() {$("#dim3").fadeOut();}, 5000);
            });

        }       
   });
}
```

Comment: @Виктор Павлов, покажите код самой формы и проверки значения.

Comment: Код формы прикрепил в вопросе. Там в форме много HTML-кода. Форма отправляется аяксом.

Comment: где JS код то??

Comment: JS добавил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не буду ходить вокруг да около.

Но то, что у тебя написано - это кошмар!

[Вот тут уже все давно решили за тебя](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/301890/php-jquery-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B), нужно только посмотреть, как и применить к своему коду. Он сразу станет красивее и начнет выполняться.

**//UPD**
Все потому, что все хотят изобретать велосипед!!!

[Пастебин](http://pastebin.com/LzKupSvF)  в помощь. Все работает, вставь функцию, ссылку дал, ведь не сложно сделать так, как нужно. Вдаваться в подробности, сколько у тебя там форм и как они работают, не буду. Вот готовый и рабочий код, который меньше в разы и приятнее к просмотру.

Твой sendForm(form) не убирал, сам сможешь убрать его. Весь json в консольке посмотри, все туда передается, как нужно.

Comment: Возможно это и кошмар, но другого варианта не вижу. Остальные поля же отправляются отлично. Проблема именно с чекбоксом.

Answer (score 0):

По умолчанию у чекбокса значение `on`. В простом варианте HTML формы он попадает в запрос в зависимости от того выбран он или нет.

Когда проверяете через JS то он и попадает в запрос.
Сначала проверте включен чекбокс или нет. И присваивайте уже в зависимости от результата.

Answer (score -1):

если вместо .value использовать .checked то всё будет работать, только вместо "on" "of" вы будете получать "true" "false".

Comment: О чём речь? Я не нашёл там ни единой строчки в которой используется пропорция `value`. Также непонятно к чему тут пропорция `checked`, это ведь jQuery там вообще нет такой пропорции. А ещё по-настоящему непонятно, к чему тут `on` / `of`?